# What is the difference between Radiative Forcing and Energy Budget

Tags: atmospheric-radiation, radiation-balance

I don't understand the difference between radiative forcing and an energy budget. They seem like the same concept to me but I cannot find anything that directly compares them.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should show your effort... They are inter-related but not the same. In simple words: Radiative forcing is "...the rate of energy change per unit area of the globe as measured at the top of the atmosphere." Earth's Energy budget takes into consideration internal energy and internal transfers at Earth. Please, start at Wikipedia and make your own research.